# How to set the charset to UTF-8 for a received http variable in PHP?

Tags: php, character-encoding

How to set the charset to UTF-8 for a received http variable in PHP?

I have a html form using the `POST` methode with 1 input field. But when i submit the form and echo the retrieved the contents from the input field via `$_POST['input_name']` i get this: KrkiÄ - but i entered (and i need) this: Krkič

So how can i fix this?

I figured it out now. :)

If i want to add the contents to MYSQL then i need to add this:

```
if(!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")){
printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n",$mysqli->error);
}
```

If i just need to echo the contents then adding this meta tag

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

into html head is enough.

Comment: Do you set the charset in your HTTP headers? (i.e., `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"');`). Also when using the htmlentities() function, you can call it with `htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")`

Comment: Do you use Apache as a webserver?

Comment: Change it in your IDE.

Comment: Displaying it in the browser/html file isn't the problem. The problem arises when i try to add something via a POST form into my database (MYSQL). If i just ECHO the content then all works fine.

Comment: I will try the `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"');` now. 1 moment. :)

Comment: Nope... this `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"');` doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check the incoming data to see which charset is it in (i.e., before sending it to MySQL)?

Comment: Can you try do dump each byte of the received string, to make sure it comes in UTF-8? Normally if you set the charset via the `Content-Type` header, the browser should send back the strings in the fields using the same charset. Try something like this:

    $s = $_POST["input_name"];
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($s); $i++) {
        echo ord($s[$i]) . ", ";
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no global default charset in PHP -- lots of things are encoding-aware, and each needs to be configured independently.

`mb_internal_encoding` applies only to the multibyte string family of functions, so it has an effect only if you are already using them (you need to do so most of the time that you operate on multibyte text from PHP code).

Other places where an incorrectly set encoding will give you problems include:

- The source file itself (saved on the disk using which encoding?)
- The HTTP headers sent to the browser (display the content received as which encoding?)
- Your database connection (which encoding should be used to interpret your queries? which encoding for the results sent back to you?)

Each of these needs to be addressed independently, and most of the time they also need to agree among themselves.

Therefore, it is not enough to say "I want to display some characters". You also need to show how you are displaying them, where they are coming from and what the advertised encoding is for your HTML.

Comment: `The source itself` - if i'm correct, then i don't need to set the charset here, as i insert the contents via html input fields and not direct from the file saved on the disk. The `Database` charset works fine. I guess that the one which i'm missing is the `HTTP POST` charset. I just don't know if i have to set the charset of the html document in which the form is displayed or somewhere in php, so that after i submit the form the charset is set?

Comment: @johansmohan: HTML input fields go without saying, so that's not adding any information. Please edit your question and add an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Guessing is a bad way to use anyone's time, including yours.

Comment: I have edited my question. Hope that now it's easier to understand my problem.

Comment: @johansmohan: It's still light on the details, but it sounds like using the Content-Type header on both pages (the one that shows the form and the one that receives the submission) should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I didn't understand it good enough before how this works. But after researching and testing i got it working. :)

Comment: I had to give the "accepted answer" to "kunal kumar" as he posted it first.

Answer (score 1):

on top of your `php` file place this

```
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"');
```